# MySQL Select Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a huge employee data in mysql with an attribute as parent id which stores the supervisor of each employee and is defined in a hierarchy. Each user is working under other employee and is handling team of 4-5 members. I frequently need the supervisor or subordinates tree for which i am using a recursive function to fetch an employ with its team. Please suggest me a method so that I don't have to call recursive function each time I need employee data. Is using "Views or stored procedure" a good idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Why, is it really giving you performance problems to do the query every time? Sounds hard to believe if it's just a few dozen records.

Comment: But maybe the mySQL query cache is worth looking at (if it's not active already): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

Comment: Do you mean that you need to fetch the entire tree for one employee, or just the next higher or tree section?

Comment: What's wrong in 4-5 primary key lookups?

Comment: @Pekka I don't have only dozens of records. I have thousands of employs in my database.

Comment: @Adrian, yes my friend I need the entire tree every time at each level. so I am facing the performance level.

Comment: @ Mr Shrapnel, How does composite key helps out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use stored procedures, you will still need recursion. You only move the recursion from the PHP source code to the database.

You can use [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) to store hierarchical data. This gets rid of recursions at the price of higher costs for insertion, deletion and relocation. Basically, you create two additional fields `left` and `right` where `left < right` and `e1` is subordinate of `e2` iff `e1.left > e2.left && e1.right < e2.right`.

This makes SELECT queries hard to read, but efficient. Do this when all else fails.

Comment: Many Thanks Mr Oswald, Please write me a little detailed code.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I got your concept from this link http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Comment: Sorry I accepted this answer late as I come to know today about it

Comment: @Umar (and anyone reading this): New address of this article: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non recursive stored procedure implementation which obviously only requires one call from your application code not n calls (one for each level of the tree). Would recommend staying well away from nested sets and stick with you adjacency list implementation - think **connect by** Oracle and **CTE** in sql server - say no more.

```
drop table if exists employees;
create table employees
(
emp_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(255) not null,
boss_id smallint unsigned null,
key (boss_id)
)
engine = innodb;

insert into employees (name, boss_id) values
('f00',null), 
  ('ali later',1), 
  ('megan fox',1), 
      ('jessica alba',3), 
      ('eva longoria',3), 
         ('keira knightley',5), 
            ('liv tyler',6), 
            ('sophie marceau',6);


drop procedure if exists employees_hier;

delimiter #

create procedure employees_hier
(
in p_emp_id smallint unsigned
)
begin

declare v_done tinyint unsigned default(0);
declare v_dpth smallint unsigned default(0);

create temporary table hier(
 boss_id smallint unsigned, 
 emp_id smallint unsigned, 
 depth smallint unsigned
)engine = memory;

insert into hier select boss_id, emp_id, v_dpth from employees where emp_id = p_emp_id;

/* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html */

create temporary table emps engine=memory select * from hier;

while not v_done do

    if exists( select 1 from employees e inner join hier on e.boss_id = hier.emp_id and hier.depth = v_dpth) then

        insert into hier select e.boss_id, e.emp_id, v_dpth + 1 
            from employees e inner join emps on e.boss_id = emps.emp_id and emps.depth = v_dpth;

        set v_dpth = v_dpth + 1;            

        truncate table emps;
        insert into emps select * from hier where depth = v_dpth;

    else
        set v_done = 1;
    end if;

end while;

select 
 e.emp_id,
 e.name as emp_name,
 p.emp_id as boss_emp_id,
 p.name as boss_name,
 hier.depth
from 
 hier
inner join employees e on hier.emp_id = e.emp_id
left outer join employees p on hier.boss_id = p.emp_id;

drop temporary table if exists hier;
drop temporary table if exists emps;

end #

delimiter ;

-- call this sproc from your php

call employees_hier(1);
```

Comment: no probs - one day (fingers crossed) mysql will have CTE or connect by functionality which will make the adj list vs nested set argument moot.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these links:

- [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)
- [Find node level in a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004183/find-node-level-in-a-tree)